# Accidental recursive cp -R, now can't delete file using either Trash or rm

Tags: macos, bash, unix

After a mistype in a path when using `cp`, I seem to have accidentally copied the folder in to itself recursively, and now I can't delete that folder using `rm -rf`, or the Trash in Mac OS X `Finder`. The file is located on the startup (therefore HFS+J) disk.

The output from `rm -rf` is just `Directory not empty` repeated, like so:

```
rm: o/old/old/old/old/old/old/old/old: Directory not empty
rm: o/old/old/old/old/old/old/old: Directory not empty
rm: o/old/old/old/old/old/old: Directory not empty
rm: o/old/old/old/old/old: Directory not empty
rm: o/old/old/old/old: Directory not empty
rm: o/old/old/old: Directory not empty
rm: o/old/old: Directory not empty
rm: o/old: Directory not empty
rm: o: Directory not empty
```

What do I do to delete this folder?

I've tried renaming the first folder, as you can see, to shorten down the file path. The folder moves in to the `Trash` fine, but won't delete because of the following alert dialog:

```
The operation can’t be completed because the item is in use.
```

Comment: Try `lsof o` to see who is using your directory `o`. Then you can see what to close. Probably you have open a terminal in that directory, and/or you start some program from that directory.

Comment: `lsof o` returns nothing, @Hastur

Comment: `fuser o` returns `o: `

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
find o -delete
```

or

```
find o -depth -delete
```

`-depth` tells `find` to go to the deepest part of the directory tree first,
and then work its way back up.  The man page says,
"Use of `-delete` automatically turns on the `-depth` option." 
If your version of `find` doesn't support `-delete`, try

```
find o -depth -exec rm -rf {} ";"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, it doesn't work: `No space left on device`

Comment: Strangely, `df -h` returns `15Gi free`

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense; these commands shouldn't be writing anything to the filesystem.  (To split hairs; delete / `rm` / unlink will overwrite directory entries with nuls, and modify the free list to add the deallocated blocks to it, but it shouldn't be doing anything that should be trying to *allocate* free blocks from the free list.)  One explanation is that `find` needs to write a temporary file to save the directory structure of your "`o`" directory tree as it reads it.  Check `df -h /tmp`.

Comment: I'm afraid it is the same response from `df -h`

Comment: Well, actually, it's `11 Gi`, but that's because I've been using my computer since, but still

Comment: The 'No space left on device' is talking about the filesystem pool.  You'll need to rename the directories to have a shorter name.  If you altered the find command above to execute a `mv` command instead of a `rm` command, this could give you the desired effect.  `find old -depth -exec mv {} o \;`.  I wish I would have read this answer a little closer before executing the `for` loop a bunch of times.

Comment: I'm going to correct my earlier comment.  The correct find command that worked with one execution was `find [root-dir] -depth -name '[name]' -execdir mv {} a \;`.  I had to search for a unique directory name in my hierarchy for this to work.  Plus I had to change `-exec` to `-execdir` so the command would be invoked from the directory containing the matched file.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just had the very same problem.  I solved it by shortening the name of *every* single one of the nested directories.

Since it is a one time problem, I did not try to come up with any smart scripting magic.  I just wrote

```
for FILE in $(ls); do mv $FILE a; cd a; done
```

in a shell, then hit the <kbd>up arrow</kbd> to call the command again, and <kbd>return</kbd>.  With one finger on each key, I just repeated the two keystrokes quickly until the deepest directory.  Then `cd ~` and `cd` to the root of the faulty tree.  A regular `rm -r` now got the job done.

Comment: I did try this. I set all the directories' names to 'o', but to no avail: they still would not delete. This is a good idea though and worth trying out if you do ever encounter such an issue.

Comment: I too did an accidentally 'cp -R'.  The rm command was failing on a file further down in the directory tree because of the nested paths.  I had to do `rm -rf old/ 2>&1 | less` to find how deep the file was.  Then I ran this `for` loop a number of times to shorten the path enough to delete the files.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you get it it's obvious. 
Because you can't recurse deep down, you should move the directory which is one level deeper just one level up. After that a directory with depth "one" remains which can be deleted.

Lets assume you have an "infinite" directory a/a/a/a/a/a/a/....

then you do:

```
mv a/a b
rm -r a
mv b/a a
rm -r b
```

Repeat until no directory is left over.

The following script does it: (you have to press ctrl-c after it finishes)

```
while [ true ]; do mv a/a b; rm -r a; mv b/a a; rm -r b; done
```

Because the names are identical the scripts 'flips' between two temporary names.